# raspberry voice commands and speaker recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, raspberry-pi3, voice-recognition

I would like to program a voice command system for raspberry. But an important point for me is that I have to recognize who is speaking, and if the person is allowed to use the system, then execute the voice command.

Is there any python library for this purpose? Mixing voice command and speaker recognition? And if it's possible usable from a raspberry pi 3.

Thank you